# Include built Nuxt app (dist folder files) application in another Nuxt.js app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs

I have two nuxt apps, but one is the main and I would like to keep them in separated repositories. Is there some way to import it in main nuxt app on a specific router that point to the second app already built?

structure:

```
app1
    ...
    node_modules/
       app2/
    pages/
       index.vue (main app)
       router-app2/
          index.vue (point to app2)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir /Development/main-app-dist
symlink ln -s /Development/main-app-dist /Development/app1/dist
symlink ln -s /Development/main-app-dist /Development/app2/dist
```

The above would make a system linked folder. However this most likely wont track via git but i've not done so, I could be wrong.